# Ubuntu can not turn the monitor on after unlock

Tags: display, unlock

Ubuntu 22.04, 5.15.0-41-generic, i12700K integrated graphics, monitor Asus pg32uq connected through HDMI. This is not a laptop. All power saving features that I could find through GUI settings are turned off.

This is what happens when the monitor is connected to Ubuntu machine only.
When the computer is locked, the monitor is blank. Pressing buttons on the keyboard does not make the monitor show any information from Ubuntu. A message "HDMI no signal" appears on the monitor from time to time. I assume that the computer starts sending signal and then stops periodically. After pressing Ctrl-Alt-F1,Ctrl-Alt-F2,Space a few times a screen with my account name appears. After I enter the password, the screen goes blank again. In most cases, it shows me Ubuntu desktop after that. In some cases, after the password is entered, the monitor shows "HDMI no signal" again and I have to repeat the process of unlocking from scratch.

The following happens when the monitor is connected to Ubuntu and Windows machines at the same time.
I have described the horror with the monitor connected to just one Linux computer above. I also have a Windows 10 laptop, which I connect to the same monitor through another HDMI port. The laptop works with this monitor perfectly, regardless of whether Ubuntu machine is connected or not. However, connecting the laptop makes the situation for Ubuntu worse. The monitor auto-switches between HDMI ports when it does not sense a signal. There is no way to turn auto-source off for this monitor. As soon as the monitor senses no signal on the port connected to the Linux machine, it switches back to the Windows machine. In many cases I find it impossible to login into Ubuntu machine without physically disconnecting the monitor from the Windows machine first. After Windows laptop is disconnected from the monitor, the situation for Ubuntu from impossible becomes terrible, as described above.

Any ideas how to make Ubuntu send a video signal all the time?